# How to create an attribute in Weka

Tags: java, weka

I working on a data mining project using WEKA in Java and the instructions says that I have to create an Attribute object for each attribute in the dataset and add them to a FastVector. I try to look at the API but I don't think I'm doing it right can someone show me the right way to do it. I'm using the iris.arff file

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;

public class StartWeka {
 public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{
  
  Instances dataset = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Student/workspace/Data Mining/src/iris.arff.txt")));
  
  Instances train = new Instances(dataset);
  train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes()-1);
  
  System.out.println(dataset.toSummaryString());
  
  Attribute a1 = new Attribute("sepallength", 0);
        Attribute a2 = new Attribute("sepalwidth", 1);
        Attribute a3 = new Attribute("petalwidth", 2);
        
        FastVector attrs = new FastVector();
  attrs.addElement(a1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FastVector is deprecated. You can use an ArrayList instead.

If you use an arff file, however, you don't have to do any of that. You can just do the following:

```
    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File("iris.arff");
    Instances structure = loader.getStructure();
    structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);
```

From here, you can create a classifier based on your instances. (structure).